# relaunching a java applet

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have built an applet which calculates things, think of it like a calculator. Now just like a calculator my applet has a clear button. A clear button is supposed to set all the variables to their default values. The problem now is that the applet is not so simple as calculator and setting so many variables has become tedious and impossible. I tried a lot. Besides i have instantiated other classes and i have to init that. It got complicated. One easy thing that I used to do when i was not making an applet but a JFrame was:

```
myFrameInstance.setVisible(false);      //hide the old frame and build a new one.
main(newInstance);
```

But the applet cannot be instantiated like that. It doesn't even have a main method. The browser takes care of that. So my question is if there is any way i can relaunch my app, like maybe hide the old one and start fresh?

Comment: A better way would be to take all the initialization you do on the variables when the applet first opens, put them into one method (something like `initVariables()`), then call that each time the clear button is pressed.

Comment: why doesn't simply calling init() work?

Comment: It depends on what's in your overridden `init()` method; chances are it would change other things you don't need or want to be reinitialized, and it could cause other problems.

Comment: Launch the applet free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and it will be almost identical to how the frame feels.